# LaTeX editors with comfortable graphics insertion functionality

Tags: editors

If I work with pictures (via `\includegraphics`) I wish that my editor (currently emacs) would have some features which makes handling images comfortable for example:

- Copy an image from another program or from the web to the clipboard and paste it in my latex file

  - file will be saved automatically in the current directory (or elswere individually configured), and probably converted to a format which `pdflatex` recognizes
  - `\includegraphics{mypic}` is inserted, either with a dialogue which lets you add some options to `\includegraphics` or with some snipped form (like in `yasnipped`).
- Drag and drop files to my latex document in a similar way to copy and paste it
- preview just the image using a keyboard shortcut if am over the image name in the `\includegraphics` comand (or alternatively start an image editor).

So are there any LaTeX editors which can handle images in such a way (at least matching one of the points above or having some other nice image handling tools), if so, how to activate the feature and how to use it.

Though currently I am using linux I am also interested in editors for other platforms.